# Getting linking errors when running C project in VS 2010 Professional on Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am getting errors of the following type :

```
1>authenticate.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ldap_first_attribute@12
1>authenticate.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ldap_first_attribute@12
1>authenticate.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ldap_value_free@4
1>authenticate.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ldap_err2string@4
```

I have already added the header file folder to Project -> Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.

Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

This is a linker error. You need to provide the library where the `_ldap_first_attribute` and other functions listed can be found. This can be either a .lib static library or a .dll dynamic library

If this refers to [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then you have to add `Wldap32.lib` to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

edit:
if this is a external library, you don't have the lib and cannot rebuild the library yourself you can either [create one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313) or use [explicit linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/784bt7z7.aspx)

Comment: it is a dll. But i do not know how to link to the dll

Comment: The dll is in a folder

Comment: it is a dll so how to do for that

Comment: if this is an external dll then you have to add its path to the Linker->General->Additional Library Directories (as well as adding the .lib to the dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `LDAP` lib.Try to configure your project correctly which points to include folder where `LDAP.lib` is present.

**Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies** will surely help.